# Short story about a scientist who (half jokingly) presented the theory that humans evolved from pigs, instead of apes

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

This was a short story from the 60's-70's.

The story was part of an anthology, perhaps from one of the magazines at the time (since it wasn't award winning material). A scientist (or doctor) at a hospital (college?) had an annoying pompous boss who was going to present irrefutable proof of man's descent from apes.  The protagonist, (mainly for revenge) presented counter evidence about the similarities between humans and pigs, internally (since omnivores tend to have similar digestive tracts, and catch the same parasites); developmentally, (pig embryos & fetuses are often used as examples, or were, since they were very similar to human embryos and fetuses.) and even externally, (relatively hairless, sunburn, sweat, even put on 'sunscreen'.

Also mentioned the old "Long Pork" line of cannibalistic societies (maybe apocryphal). The punch line, I believe, was about the fact that the father of the scientific method was, of course, named "Bacon". Any help?

Comment: Welcome! Could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and see if there is anything else you can [edit] in?

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like Alan E Nourse' *Family Resemblance*. Iirc it appeared in an anthology entitled *Tiger By the Tail*. It was first published in *Astounding* in April 1953 and later in Groff Conklin's *Science Fiction Adventures in Mutation*.

In addition to various physical similarities between pigs and men, it is also pointed out that they resemble each other psychologically.

> "Why are pigs used for conditioning experiments now,  in preference to rats and dogs and cats? *Because they react more like man*. The pig stands far above cats and dogs nd rats and many monkey species on the intelligence scale. And what other animal, Dr Hogan, besides man, is so consistently lazy, gluttonous, dirty, selfish, treacherous, or pugnacious?"

It finished with a crack about "Roger Bacon".

Comment: Good answer. Don't know why the question had to be migrated.

Comment: [ISFDB link](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55925) for this story.